# Subtract last and first elements in a column using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A B C Date
2 3 6 03/19/2012 2:33:34.270103 PM
4 8 2 03/19/2012 2:33:34.270308 PM
...
6 2 0 03/19/2012 2:34:04.611729 PM
```

So I need to calculate the time difference between the last element and first element in the column 'Date'. I need the time difference in seconds for

```
(10/21/2014 2:34:04.611729 PM) - (03/19/2012 2:33:34.270103 PM) =  ANSWER to print out
```

Also, the date format I have is exactly as shown above. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the `Date` series to datetime first using the `to_datetime` method, then it's just a simple computation from there.

```
In [24]: df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

In [25]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

In [26]: delta = df['Date'].iat[-1] - df['Date'].iat[0]

In [27]: delta
Out[27]: numpy.timedelta64(30300000000,'ns')

In [28]: delta / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
Out[28]: 30.300000000000001
```

Line 28 is to "standardize" the result to seconds, as the initial result was in nanoseconds.

**EDIT:**

Basing it on the CSV you uploaded, the issue here is that your dates are of a format that is not readily convertible to datetime. You need to truncate the first two and the last characters before converting. Following code works and provides the correct target value.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv("dummy.csv")

In [4]: str_ = lambda x:x[2:-1]

In [5]: df["Timestamp"] = df["Timestamp"].map(str_)

In [6]: df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])

In [7]: delta_ = df["Timestamp"].iat[-1] - df["Timestamp"].iat[0]

In [8]: delta_
Out[8]: numpy.timedelta64(36981327000,'ns')

In [9]: delta_ / np.timedelta64(1, "s")
Out[9]: 36.981327
```

Kindly let us know if this works.

Comment: `iat` is deprected, better to use `iloc`:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position

Comment: I am getting this error if I use iat.


        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "./a.py", line 36, in <module>
            Total_time = d['Timestamp'].iat[-1] -         d['Timestamp'].iat[0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: @mane you have to convert to a datetime first did you try `pd.to_datetime(d['Timestamp'])`?

Comment: Yes. I have done that. Converted to 

`d['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(d['Timestamp'])`

Comment: I have converted `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])` but when I do 

`df.dtypes`, it still shows 

`Delta                           object

Timestamp                       object

Unnamed: 22                    float64

frameduration                  float64

dtype: object`

So, I also tried `df['Timestamp'].astype('datetime64[ns]')` but that also doesn't seem to work. 

Any clues?

Comment: Also, it shows this error at the end:

`Total_time = d['Timestamp'].iat[-1] - d['Timestamp'].iat[0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: You said you did `df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])`, but based on your later statements, it shows that your dataframe is not `df` but `d`. Are you sure you converted the correct dataframe? If yes, then it's quite possible that your dates are not converted from strings. That error appears when you're trying to subtract a string from a string, obviously.

Comment: FYI iat is NOT deprecated

Comment: @Nanashi I have just used `d` and `df` arbitrarily here but I am using the same dataframe consistently. And, yes, the datetime conversion doesnt not seem to have worked since it is still showing `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' –`

Comment: This might be a bit radical but can you upload your CSV/text file online and post a link in your post? I can suggest a couple of ways but I have to see how Pandas reads the data exactly so I can provide a solution.

Comment: @Nanashi Here is the link to the CSV file. The column of interest is the last column called Timestamp: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1QoW8g6KGj3dEhtWUtVR1R6eTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think I see the issue now. The format is far from what you provided above since it's showing `="10/22/2014 5:22:54.408590 PM"`. That's most definitely a string and needs to be sanitized before conversion to datetime format. Wait a moment while I fix it.